# Intermittent 100% CPU running e.g. Firefox or Libre Office writer on 12.04 Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, cpu

Occasionally some applications lock and their windows goes dark or changes colour. This has happened most frequently when running Firefox but happened today when running Libre Office Writer and pasting an image. The system monitor shows 100% CPU on these occasions but I am able to kill the appropriate process.

This is most frustrating and does not give me confidence in using Unity especially as I have never had a similar problem running 10.04 Gnome.

Please let me know what detail/log is needed so to provide information so that the problem may be diagnosed/fixed.

Comment: Have you looked at turning off hardware acceleration?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I have always noticed gnome-system monitor uses around 25% cpu with not a single app open,and can spike for no apparent reason.startin libre office and firefox i noticed when left idle firefox spikes up to 90% cpu usage for no apparent reason also.However looking at the compiz % it always rather low which points to it not being a unity issue

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1064474 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=863644 etc. Possibly also sth to do with gmail (and javascript).